# Как не выходя из Android Studio получить развернутый лог gradle'а?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

После сборки в Messages появляется достаточно краткая сводка того, что случилось в процессе сборки. Есть ли возможность получить туда результат, аналогичный `gradle --debug`? Ну или не туда, но еще куда-нибудь не выходя из студии.

Comment: Возможно вам нужна кнопка `show console output` в `Messages`?

Comment: Или вот это? http://stackoverflow.com/a/37266244/3212712

Comment: show console output - это оно, спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В панели `Messages` есть кнопка `show console output` - при нажатии на неё появляется окно `Gradle console` - там выхлоп нужный. Вот скрин:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]